# CSS Background Image doesn't display

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I think I have everything defined correctly but the background image doesn't show. Here's the code and jsfiddle, (I used the google logo for the background image in this example. I assume that works?)

```
#main_links a span {
    display: none;
}
#main_links {
    top: 100px;
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 728px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 38px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#main_links li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px 20px 0 0;
    height: 29px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
#link1 a {
    width: 113px;
    display: block;
    background: url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png') no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SqHE8/

Comment: Since you removed all content from the `a` elements, they get no height until you set one.

Comment: Explaining better, the problem is not the height or the elements being removed. The problem is that the `a` content is not visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @CBroe comment is precise (you are not displaying the `a` content). Then, to see the image you need to set the image to background of `#link1` and not `#link1 a`:

```
#link1 a {
    width: 113px;
    display: block;
}

#link1 {
    background: url('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: it's kind of funny that you get the reputation points for CBRoe's answer, but he should have posted it in the answer section and not the comments section

Answer (score 0):

Do the following Check:

1. Check the image URL.
2. Set `min-height` for the image container.
3. Set `background-size`.

If the image URL is correct, the possible reason for missing image is you do not set background-size.